# Sort a string array without using the split method in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an array with month names:

```
String[] months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                   "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct","Nov", "Dec"};
```

I want to sort this array. I tried different codes but failed.

How can I sort this array without using the split method?

Comment: What kind of sort do you need? Alphabetical or sort by month order!?

Comment: @mehrandvd - they are already in month order, but sorting on name seems so ... odd.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting upvoted, doesn't show research effort

Comment: The question is neither clear nor complete. What is the expected result, does it have to be in-place etc.

Comment: Where would Split come into this at all?

Comment: @JamieHutber - [there is no need to add tags to the title.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147063)

Answer (score 3):

a simple

```
Array.Sort(month);
```

sort the array by the names.

if you want different kind of sorting you can use Sort with `IComparer` of your own.

for example, a simple one

```
public class myComp : IComparer<string>
{

  #region IComparer<string> Members

  public int Compare(string x, string y)
  {
     return x.ToLower().CompareTo(y.ToLower());
  }

  #endregion
}
```

and then do

```
Array.Sort(month, new myComp());
```

Comment: Could you add an example of how that IComparer is used?

Comment: @Default edited the answer for that

Comment: i was asking without sort method. :)

Comment: @great actually your words are: "without using the split method" :)
you wand to implement sort? is that it?

Comment: @great You can get some inspiration on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Popular_sorting_algorithms). I believe `Array.Sort` uses some kind of [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), but you can check its documentation and/or source code.

Comment: @great you haven't replied... if you got your answer from one of the given answer mark it as accepted, if not please tell us what's more to it

Comment: yes you are right thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could sort them like this:

```
var sortedList = months.OrderBy (s => s).ToArray();
```

You can substitute `s=>s` part with any other sorting key as you like. For example if you want to sort by their second character you could write this:

```
var sortedList = months.OrderBy (s => s[1]).ToArray();
```

FYI, `OrderBy` method is a part of LINQ which comes with C# 3.0. So you should have `using System.Linq` in your file.

Comment: And the OP may want to replace `ToList()` with `ToArray()`. In both cases a _new_ list/array is created.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yep, you're right. I just used to use `ToList()` immediately. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
string[] month= new string[]
        {
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
            "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct","Nov", "Dec"
        };

        Array.Sort(month, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);

        Array.ForEach(month, x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```